# WPA Enterprise problem connect

Tags: networking, wifi, wpa

The only way I've found to connect to an Enterprise AP is to modify the wpa_supplicant.conf file, adding this:

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
update_config=1
country=IT
ap_scan=2
fast_reauth=1

network={
    scan_ssid=1
    ssid="SSID-name"
    key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
    eap=PEAP
    identity="user"
    phase1="peaplabel=0"
    phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
    password="password"
```

Now, let's say I have the same router, SSID and pwd at home **and** at work: should I be able to connect to both of them with the same credential I use for one of them? (ie, if I modify wpa_supplicant.conf for the home-wifi, can I automatially connect to the work-wifi when I am there?)

If no, how can I differentiate the two, if all the parameter are the same?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From `man wpa_supplicant.conf`:

> Configuration  file  can  include one or more network blocks, e.g., one for each used SSID. wpa_supplicant will automatically select the best
>          network based on the order of network blocks in the configuration file, network security level (WPA/WPA2 is preferred), and signal strength.

In other words, just add another `network=` block for each SSID you want to be able to potentially connect to.  If they are in separate places, obviously the selection algorithm referred to above will not matter.

Comment: So my Raspberry and a particular SSID are not linked with a "key", which makes the connection unique? I just need to enter the SSID and password and if I find another network with the same informations, will it connect?
My worry was that after one connection, that password and username were "stored" with a key of that particular AP making it unique.

Comment: I don't understand you.  Does this have to do with switching SSID's when you are in an area where there is more than one listed in `wpa_supplicant.conf`?  You can have as many as you like in there, but if they are in physically different areas there's no conflict.  You should connect to whichever one is applicable.  The "key" you are referring to is just a conceptualization of yours, correct?

Comment: I think what he's meaning is, let's say there are 2 networks with exactly the same credentials, in different locations. If you save the credentials on wpa_supplicant for one fo the networks (say, the first time you connect to the network at your home). would this be enough to connect to another network automatically which has the same SSID and password requirements?

Comment: Good question.  My hunch is it will not know the difference.  You can run `wpa_supplicant` in the foreground if you want some details about what's working and how (but you will probably need to disable auto-networking stuff first).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes, what @LecauseAndThePi says it's what I wanted to express.
My main problem is also that I need to connect to that one AP from the terminal because it is grayed out in the GUI network panel. For this reason I need to modify the wpa_supplicant.conf file on the go.